# How to configure Etags in Sitecore?

Tags: caching, sitecore, browser-cache, etags

Could you someone have experience configuring Etags in Sitecore 8.1?  I do not see all images coming from Media library has response cache header ETag.

I have verified in Most modern browsers chrome and Firefox Network Tab.

Thanks
Mala

Answer (score 8):

Change the MediaResponse.Cacheability setting in App_Config\Sitecore.config to Public:

```
<setting name="MediaResponse.Cacheability" value="Public" />
```

Once the setting is changed, the result as shown in Fiddler:

[image]

FYI, other settings are:

- NoCache: nobody can cache the page.
- Private: only browsers can cache.
  it (but not shared proxies). This is the default value.
- Public: everybody can cache the page, proxies included.
- Server: pages are cached only on the server (like the NoCache, so browsers don't cache the page).
- ServerAndNoCache: Server and NoCache... the same as Server.
- ServerAndPrivate: Server and Private... the same as Private.

NOTE: To follow Sitecore's Best Practice, instead of changing direct changes to Ssitecore configs, create the following patch file (MediaResponseCacheabilityPublic.config) in `\App_Config\Include\zzz\` folder:

```
   <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" >
      <sitecore>
        <settings>
          <setting name="MediaResponse.Cacheability" set:value="Public" />
        </settings>
      </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```